# Error while trying to debug D program

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, d

My problem is that when I try to start debuggin in DDT in Eclipse (Kepler) an error shows up:

> Error in final launch sequence
>    Failed to execute MI command:
>   -gdb-set auto-solib-add on
>   Error message from debugger back end:
>   No symbol table is loaded.
>   Use the "file" command.
>     No symbol table is loaded.
>   Use the "file" command.

I've compiled the application with -gc and -g flag but it didn't help.

I'm using original DMD compiler.

Comment: What happens if you run GDB from the terminal?

Comment: Same error, additionally it says tha file is not in executable format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are working on Windows, DMD has no GDB support there yet. You can either use [windbg](http://dlang.org/windbg.html) from the command line or use the [Visual Studio](http://rainers.github.io/visuald/visuald/StartPage.html) plugin, which converts the debug info after compiling.

Comment: Do you know any IDE that supports any good debugging for D and has some well established features like syntax highlighting and autocompletion?

Comment: I mainly use DDT, when the need to debug arises I use the VS plugin (which is pretty neat on its own) or switch to Linux. VisualD can be installed in the free Visual Studio Shell, take a look at VisualD's installation page for more information.

Comment: Sometime age I've tried the VisualD with VS shell. So you split coding from debugging and use two different IDE's for each task? Or do you do coding also in VisualD? The thing is that I had problems enabling completion and other language features in VS Shell when using D and I don't know if this has something to do with the fact that docs say: "The shells are identical with the Visual Studio IDE, but stripped of any language support. "

Comment: When I have to debug I also code in VS, but after that I switch back to Eclipse because I enjoy its keyboard shortcut abilities more. I haven't tried the Shell yet due to having a Student DreamSpark account, so I can't really help you there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I had is that the compiler (DMD) is not working with GDB under Windows. If somebody wants to use DDT with debugging support, he needs to use GDC compiler.
This actually is mentioned in the "Debugging" page:
http://wiki.dlang.org/Debugging